Advice for assigning student projects in masters data science stats course
I'd like some advice on assigning final projects in an applied stats course that I'm developing as part of a master's in data science program.
I don't have a lot of experience assigning student projects, and have never done it at the master's level.
One particular piece of advice I'd like is some guidelines for students to select a dataset for a final project. In said final project, I want students to ask at least one (is that enough?) interesting research question. Answering that question would ideally require them to employ most of the techniques learned in the course.
Here are some examples of the kind of advice I have in mind. Feel free to let me know why any example I've suggested is a bad idea.

require at least _ continuous numerical variables, _ of which are continuous and _ categorical
avoid datasets that are of the _ type
require _ visualizations (where blank could be a number or a type)

Here are the topics of the course:

Frequentist unit topics:
central limit theorem,
hypothesis testing,
confidence intervals,
ANOVA,
linear regression,
logistic regression.

Bayesian unit topics:
hypothesis testing,
confidence intervals,
ANOVA,
linear regression,
logistic regression.

Machine learning unit topics:
KNN,
regularized regression,
linear & quadratic discriminant analysis,
support vector machines,
decision trees (w/ boosting & bagging).


